# Any alternatives to web services when doing a legacy system integration?

Tags: web-services, architecture, vb6, data-integration

Let's say that I have this case:

A legacy **visual basic 6** application which can't connect to web services in general (XML soap or restful API) that works as a client application that needs to integrate in some way it's data which practically came from forms inputs, with other systems mostly developed in .net

So far what I have thought about:

- Sockets connections
- Transfer files via FTP (implement an adapter
  to read and parse the information to the other system)
- Email send
  (client) / parse (server) - this is not reliable

any other options for this scenario?

Comment: You can write a web service consumer in .NET then expose it as a COM object which can be consumed by VB6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.Net WCF isn't just a problem for VB6.  WCF has notorious interoperability issues since there is a ton in there that is highly proprietary to .Net's own little world.

SOAP is slowly dying away, but sadly lingers in .Net shops because of several factors such as hanging back on early .Net versions and a general inertia.  Avoid it where possible.

RESTful and RESTlike APIs aren't really hard to use in VB6.  The biggest obstacles are usually HMAC-based authentication techniques, JSON serialization, and so on since Microsoft never bothered to make any VB6 tooling available.  There is plenty of support for HTTP and XML though.

There are also a ton of community created and 3rd party code samples and products out there to use in HTTP-based APIs.  The trick is selecting among them and then performing the necessary integration.

But I get the impression this isn't in the cards for you.

Don't discard MSMQ too quickly as another possible option.

Comment: I don't think it's fair to call wcf proprietary. if anything, the problems with wcf stem from how configurable it is.

Answer (score 0):

Basically all the internet protocols(HTTP, FTP, SMTP) are made for data transfer. And they all go through sockets. You could communicate between two points using any of them.

It really depends on the data you want to transfer.

Personalty, I think that a custom made one would fit the best. 
It's trivial in .net to send UDP packages using sockets. And you can define your data there as you wish.

Comment: thanks for the answer but, what do you mean with " I think that a custom made one would fit the best."?

Comment: With custom one I was referring to a custom definition of the data structure and the communication between endpoints (which is the protocol). But your choice should depend on the data that you want to transfer and the systems that need to exchange data. You could even consider a mediator between the legacy system and the other systems. It could communicate with the VB6 through sockets and with the other systems through the RESTful interface.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the option of using queues (if Possible). I've seen a few documents before which integrate MSMQ with other vendor messaging systems. Ex. MSMQ to Tibco, etc.

You do get the benefit straightaway because then you can create the adapters to communicate with messaging system and then have the freedom to choose any format of the message that you would want to exchange.